# Instantiating subclass objects from baseclass-templated list

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a list of template objects which are templated after different subclasses of a base class. I know that lists can't be heterogeneous, so typedef'd my list of templates after a list of those Base Classes.

Check below for the basic code. The problem comes when I try to instantiate the implemenation from within the template, since it's still assuming that I'm using an abstract base class, even though I have passed its subclasses in the template argument.

This is all done in the header.

```
// Base Class
class MyBase {
public:
    MyBase(int a) {}

    virtual void Print() = 0;
};

// Subclass ONE
class MySub_One : 
    public MyBase 
{
public:
    MySub_One(int a) 
        : MyBase(a) {}

    virtual void Print() override { printf("Sub One\n"); }
};

// Subclass TWO
class MySub_Two : 
    public MyBase 
{
public:
    MySub_Two(int a) 
        : MyBase(a) {}

    virtual void Print() override { printf("Sub Two\n"); }
};



// Template Class
template <class T>
class MyTemplate
{
    int numPrint;

    void CreateAndPrint()
    {
        T* obj = new T(0); // Compiler says, "error C2259: 'MyBase' Cannot instantiate abstract class."

        obj = dynamic_cast<MyBase>( obj );
        obj->Print(); 
    }
};
```

When I later add a subclass object to a baseclass list, there's also a problem:

```
list<MyTemplate<MyBase>*> testList = list<MyTemplate<MyBase>*>();
testList.push_back( new MyTemplate<MySub_One>() ); // This is a problem too
```

What causes these two errors? Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of problems.

1. `MyTemplate<MyBase>` is not a base class of `MyTemplate<MySub_One>`
2. You are trying add a pointer of type `MyTemplate<MySub_One>*` to a list that is supposed to hold a list of objects of type `MyTemplate<MyBase>`.

You need something like:

```
class TemplateBase
{
  public:
    virtual void CreateAndPrint() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class MyTemplate : public TemplateBase
{
  public:
    virtual void CreateAndPrint()
    {
        T* obj = new T(0);
        obj->Print(); 
    }
};

list<TemplateBase*> testList;
testList.push_back( new MyTemplate<MySub_One>() );
```

Comment: 1. That was actually a typo - the original was a list of pointers. Adding the pointer to the above code made no difference. However...
2. I'll try that out - looks promising.